# Javascript - Validação de Nome e Sobrenome com letras maiúsculas no início

Tags: javascript

Boa noite pessoal,
Fiz um javascript para corrigir um cadastro de pessoa física de modo a criar o padrão *Nome e Sobrenome*, por exemplo, ***João da Silva.***

Consegui o que queria quando o usuário digita tudo em caixa baixa. Porém, se o usuário digita tudo em caixa alta (JOÃO DA SILVA) o javascript não corrige e deixa tudo em caixa alta mesmo. 
  Gostaria que também corrigi-se caso fosse digitado também em caixa alta, caso o usuário esqueça o CAPSLOCK ligado.

```js
function formatanome(nome){
 
   var letra, tamanho;
   
   tamanho = nome.length;
   
   for (var i=0; i<tamanho; i++)
   {
  letra = nome.charAt(i);
      if (letra== " ")
         if ((i+1)<tamanho)
     {
        letra = nome.charAt(i+1).toUpperCase();
        nome = nome.substring(0, i+1);
  nome += letra;
        nome += document.getElementById("nome").value.substring(i+2, tamanho);
     }
   }
   
   if (tamanho>0)
   {
      letra = nome.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
      nome = nome.substring(1, tamanho);      
      nome = letra + nome;
   }
   document.getElementById("nome").value = nome;
}
```

```html
<html>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>


<form name="dispositivo">NIP<input id="nip" type="text" size="8" onblur="inteiro()"/>

ID<input id="resultado" type="readonly" size="8" />

NOME<input id="nome" type="text" size="40" onblur="formatanome(this.value)"/>
</form>
```

Comment: a dificuldade é deixar o `da` em minusculas

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png

Comment: Se uma resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como acceita, veja como no link do comentário acima e porque em  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: A utilização de uma Regex não resolveria o seu problema de uma maneira mais simples e enxuta?

Answer (score 3):

> Para todos os casos - exemplos de entradas no `input`

```
nOME sobREnome,  NOME SOBRENOME, nome sobrenome, etc...
```

Veja seu funcionamento

```js
function formatanome(nome){

  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;

  nome = nome.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(capitalize) { return capitalize.toUpperCase(); });

  document.getElementById("nome").value=nome;

}
```

```html
<form name="dispositivo">
NOME<input id="nome" type="text" size="40" onblur="formatanome(this.value)"/>
</form>
```

### Explicações

> transforme tudo em minusculas

```
nome.toLowerCase()
```

> e depois faça um replace retornando uma nova string com todas as combinações do padrão substituído (substr ou uma RegExp) por um substituidor ( uma novaSubStr ou uma função ).

Sintaxe do método replace()

```
nome.replace(RegExp|substr, novaSubStr|função)
```

Simplificando para melhor entendimento:

```
nome.replace(substituído, substituidor)
```

**Para todos os casos a seguir usarei como substituído a regex abaixo**

```
//substituído /(?:^|\s)\S/g
```

- substituidor string `BBBB`

  ```
  nome.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g,'BBBB');
  ```
- substituidor uma `função`

  A nova versão do JavaScript, a ES6, trouxe novas features e dentre elas uma nova forma de criar funções usando o operador `=>`. Esta nova forma de se trabalhar com funções são chamadas  [**Arrow Functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

  - com retorno implícito - substituidor `(X) => X.toUpperCase()`

    ```
    nome.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, (X) => X.toUpperCase() );
    ```
  - sem retorno implícito - substituidor `(X) => { return X.toUpperCase() }`

    ```
    nome.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, (X) => { return X.toUpperCase() } );
    ```
  - sem arrow function ES6 - `function(X) { return X.toUpperCase() }`

    ```
    nome.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(X) { return X.toUpperCase(); });
    ```
  - Todas essas três funções fazem a mesma coisa.

> OBSERVAÇÕES:

A - a letra **`X`** usada nos casos acima, é arbitrária. Poderia ter sido, por exemplo, substituida por `qqcoisa` ou `capitalize` ou o que quiser que seja. Exemplo:  no caso 1

`(qqcoisa) => qqcoisa.toUpperCase()` ou `(capitalize) => capitalize.toUpperCase()`.

B - a expressão regular `/(?:^|\s)\S/g` faz pesquisa global, obtendo a primeira letra após um espaço em branco.

---

---

### E caso as preposições não devar ser capitalizadas temos

```js
function formatanome(nome){

   var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;

   nome = nome.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(capitalize) { return capitalize.toUpperCase(); });
  
   var PreposM = ["Da","Do","Das","Dos","A", "E"];
   var prepos = ["da","do","das","dos","a", "e"];

   for (var i = PreposM.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     nome = nome.replace(RegExp("\\b" + PreposM[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "\\b", "g"), prepos[i]);
   }

document.getElementById("nome").value=nome;

}
```

```html
<form name="dispositivo">
NOME<input id="nome" type="text" size="40" onblur="formatanome(this.value)"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um método capitalizador.

1. Dê um UpperCase para o primeiro caracter.
2. this.slice(1), pega o ponto com texto a partir segundo carácter e dá um LowerCase.
3. Concatenar os dados.
4. Retornar os dados.

Gerando um método capitalize para a classe string:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function () {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Aplicação do método na execução:

```
// Formata o nome de forma capitalizada.
function formatanome(nome) {
    // Tamanho da string.
    var tamanho;
    tamanho = nome.length;
    // Se texto for maior que 1 posição deixa tudo em minúsculas e coloca a primeira letra em maiúsculas.
    if (tamanho > 1) {
        nome = nome.capitalize();
    } else {
        nome = nome.toUpperCase();
    }
    // Devolve o valor capitalizado caso ele seja maior que 1 posição.
    document.getElementById("nome").value = nome;
}
```